# Where to manipulate data after controller grabs it from entity in zf2

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2

In zf2, I'm writing a viewAction that grabs a record from a doctrine entity and passes the data to a view.  After I've grabbed the data and before I pass it to the view, there's a bunch of conversion, formatting, concatenation, parsing and other manipulation I want to do to it.  For example, the script below develops different `$eventDate` and `$eventTime` strings depending upon whether an event is a single- or multi-day event:

```
if ($eventStartDate==$eventEndDate) {
    $eventStartDate = $eventStartDate->format('n/j/y');
    $eventEndDate = $eventEndDate->format('n/j/y');
    $eventDate = $eventStartDate;

    $eventStartTime = $eventStartTime->format('g:i a');
    $eventEndTime = $eventEndTime->format('g:i a');
    $eventTime = "<strong>time: </strong>" . $eventStartTime . " - " . $eventEndTime . "<br/>";

} else {
    $eventStartDate = $eventStartDate->format('n/j');
    $eventEndDate = $eventEndDate->format('n/j/y');
    $eventDate = $eventStartDate . " - " . $eventEndDate;

    $eventStartTime = $eventStartTime->format('g:i a');
    $eventEndTime = $eventEndTime->format('g:i a');
    $eventTime = "<strong>departure: </strong>" . $eventStartTime . "<br/>";
    $eventTime .= "<strong>return: </strong>" . $eventEndTime . "<br/>";

}
```

This is just one of a collection of similar scripts that I've got written in my controller.  However, in an MVC pattern, it doesn't seem like they belong there. My question is, where should this and similar scripts be written?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need a [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) to apply such business logic, process your entity, generate a result and return that result back to the caller rather than handling all of this logic in controller level.

ZF's built-in [Service Manager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html) would be good place to take a look.

I would handle that requirement by following steps:

1. Write an `EventService` class under `Application\Service` namespace. This `EventService` depends on doctrine's `EventRepository` and/or `ObjectManager`'s itself. Pass this dependencies to the `EventService` on construction time (you'll need a factory) or take a look [ObjectManagerAwareInterface](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Persistence/ObjectManagerAwareInterface.php) to figure out other ways (ie: [setter injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Three_types_of_dependency_injection)).
2. This `EventService` would have some public methods like `getEventById($id)`, `getEventsByDateInterval(\DateTime $from, \DateTime $to)`, `getActiveEvents()` etc..
3. These public methods like `getEventById($id)` are interfaces for your controllers to interact your application.
4. `EventService` should/may have some private methods which doesn't accessible from outside and apply some domain rules on resultset or manipulate the [business objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object) or even generates some other lightweight [data transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) for specific use cases, internally.
5. Write a `FooEvent` entity. This entity would have some properties like `$id`, `$title`, `$startDate`, `$endDate` and these entity properties probably will be persisted to database.
6. In `FooEvent` entity, write a one-line public method named `isSingleDayEvent()` which returns a boolean.

Something like:

```
public function isSingleDayEvent()
{
    return $this->getStartDate() === $this->getEndDate();
}
```

After all of this fancy steps, our viewAction can be written something like this:

```
   public function viewAction()
   {
      $id = (int) $this->params()->fromQuery('id');
      // Event instance can be an actual entity or DTO
      $event = $this->eventService->getEventById($id);
      $viewModel = new ViewModel();
      $viewModel->setVariable('event', $event);

      return $viewModel;
   }
```

7. Now, we can write a [ViewHelper](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html) with a name like `EventRenderer` to easily render events on view layer. The key point is our view helper accepts an `\FooEvent` (or DTO) instance to work. (This is not a MUST too)

For example:

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Application\Entity\FooEvent;

class EventRenderer extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke(FooEvent $event)
    {
        $time = '';

        if($event->isSingleDayEvent()) {
          $time = '<strong>Time: </strong>: '. $event->getStartTime();
        } else {
          $time = '<strong>Time: </strong>: '. $event->getStartTime();
        }

        return $time;
    }
}
```

I simplified the helper for the sake of other key points.

And finally, inside the `view.phtml`, we can output the result of all this complex processes writing fewer lines:

```
echo '<h1>Event: '.$this->event->getTitle().'</h1>';
echo $this->eventRenderer($this->event);
```

By this way, in the next stages of your project when you need a REST service for example, writing and API endpoint will be easy as pie: writing a `RestfulEventController` will be enough **while re-using whole service layer, without duplicating bunch of code**.

I tried to summarize some best practices from my perspective, some steps definitely can be improved. I write this detailed answer because I asked similar questions several times in the past and couldn't find the exact answer but the partial solutions.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to provide a detailed answer.  Like you, I find that the web has a lot of partial solutions; but also that there is a lot of reference material for what “can” be done, and very little on what “should” be done, and why.  I’ve got two questions and I’ve put them into separate comments:

Comment: Currently, I’ve got my entities and repositories all set, and I use Doctrine’s EntityManager to grab the data.  I’ve got functionality like your `getEventsByDateInterval()` and `getActiveEvents()`, but it is written in the repositories.  So, instead of `$events = $this->eventService-> getEventsByDateInterval (params)` I call the data with `$ events = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(FooEvent)->getPagedEvents( params )`.  Should I have a Service Manager in addition to/instead of Doctrine’s EntityManager?

Comment: I like the idea of creating the function `isSingleDayEvent()` in an entity.  Why shouldn’t I also create an `eventDate()` and `eventTime()` function there as well instead of in view helpers?  It seems like putting all of the data manipulation functions into the entity instead of in view helpers would reduce the amount of code because I wouldn’t have to create all the helper files and register them all.  Is the use of the helpers better practice or does it improve functionality?

Comment: For the first question, yes adding another layer may sounds like bad but directly accessing to repository or entity manager's itself from controller is worse. Service layer should decide the data source. For example; what do you do if you want to get that result from another database, or cache after running a query against the db? What do you do if you want to get the result from another source like solr, redis, even filesystem on specific cases? For the sake of maintainability and extensibility, having a service layer between the data sources and controllers would be a good practice.